# How to change the title of ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, babel, naming

I need to change default title of ToC. Is it possible with `titlesec` package?
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\thechapter}{1em}{} \vspace{6pt}]

\usepackage{lipsum}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{footnote} {0}\chapter*{{\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont\normalfont{Author1} \\
{\scshape\Large Title}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\normalfont{Author1} \\ \normalfont\scshape{Title}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Author{Author1}
\Title{Title}
\lipsum
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}



\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) because it's far from minimal. Also you don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: @N.N. is it MWE now? I think I have to use {titlesec} in my preamble to show you.

Comment: I think it's can be more minimal. Please read the link I supplied carefully.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

How you change the title of the table of contents depends on if you're using the `babel` package or not.

### Without babel or polyglossia

You can [change the name](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-fixnam) of the table of contents by redefining `\contentsname` as the following illustrates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

### With babel or polyglossia

If you use either the `babel` or `polyglossia` package you'll have to [change the name for the particular language you use with babel or polyglossia](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords). Say that you load babel or polyglossia with `english`, then you do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Whatever}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Either way you'll end up with the following result:

[image: Title of table of contents changed to "Whatever"]

Comment: My babel language was `USEnglish`; I had to change the command to `\captionsUSenglish`.

Comment: It might be dependent on document class or babel vs polyglossia (or possibly a compilation engine): for me, with ``book`` class and Lua(La)TeX, ``\captionsUSenglish`` doesn't work with polyglossia's ``\setdefaultlanguage[variant=us]{english}``, but ``\captionsenglish`` does.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to N.N's solution that some might prefer if they're using the `Memoir` class is to redefine `\printtoctitle` instead of changing `\contentsname` directly. The reason for this is that often (and apparently by default) the ToC will list a reference to its own page within itself, and it will use `\contentsname` for both the ToC title and the reference, which can produce a jarring discontinuity of style with other chapter listings within the ToC.

With `printtoctitle` you can avoid this problem, since as described on page 147 of the [Memoir manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), it's used to call `\contentsname` during ToC title creation, so you can shift all the formatting there instead.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{memsty}

% This works well.
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\Huge\sffamily #1}

% This won't work well.
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\Huge\sffamily Contents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}

\end{document}
```