# Creating Table of Contents / Section Headings

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, formatting, page-breaking, naming

I found this article and would like to know how can one create a template (generic) to accomplish this. It would be great to implement a (generic) template to be able to make it for a table of contents, list of figures, list of tables, list of listings (code), etc... I would like the table of contents, table of figures, etc.. to all start on a fresh page instead of running on from the previous section. I will post a external like because you will able to get a better idea of what I am asking. I could post a picture, but the functionality would be taken away, i.e., being able to click the link and it takes you to the appropriate part of the document. I would like to know how is this done for contents,figures, sections, references, footnotes, etc. Also, if one can include how to play around with the color of the wording for the contents would be great. Can I also add, (I know its already a lot, but I think this is the last thing) I would like to be able to move the contents, list of figures, list of tables to the center of the page and I would like if I could have control of what to name them, i.e., Table of Contents instead of Contents produced from `\tableofcontents,\listofigures,\listoftables`. Okay I will stop here, its already a lot to digest I think.

- [microtype](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf)
- [TOC and Headings](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/CRing.pdf) (This is the document that has the centered and underlined section titles that I would like to accomplish).

Comment: Some modification depend on you document class. Which one do you use?

Comment: HEy Marco! How you been buddy? I am using the `report` class. I wanted to use `article` but I get some unwanted issues with paging. Its skips pages leaving blank ones, and a creates a lot of messiness (with errors). I tried `book`, but was a few issues with that as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the `memoir` class? It provides hooks and commands to accomplish pretty much everything on your wish list.

Comment: Mico: No I haven't. Never had to use that package before. It will be something I look into. Thanks `:)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `report` class, the table of contents and related lists are typeset as (unnumbered) chapters, i.e., *with* a page break before them. To center chapter titles and add a rule below them, use the [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. To rename the ToC & friends, redefine the `\contentsname`, `\listfigurename`, and`\listtablename` macros. (If you're using `babel`, have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc) question.)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\Large\bfseries\centering}%
    {\chaptername~\thechapter}{1ex}{}[\titlerule]

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Page 1:

[image]

Page 2:

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot. That really helped. I got two more small (I think) problems if you can help. First is, the `[pdflatex]{hyperref}` is creating red boxes around everything. How can you control this to style to one's pleasure including colors and removing frames? Second is, I have issues with my referencing. Say if I put a graphics file in section 3.4, on the `listoffigures`, it will show up with 3.1 next to it? Whats going on with that you think?

Comment: @nightowl: `hyperref` offers a lot of configuration options -- to simlply remove the colored boxes, use the `hidelinks` option. (You need an up-to-date TeX distribution to do so.) With regard to your referencing issues, please ask a new question and include a minimal working example.

Comment: Okay, says `hidelinks` is undefined. Could you add a line in the code about the `color` of the text for the contents and list of figures?

Comment: @nightowl: Try to add `\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}` at the end of your preamble.

Comment: Nice: `:)`, so I see the third element takes care of the frames and how thick they are, but what are the first two zero elements represent? Can you alter the color of the text using these, say if I wanted blue, green, text?

Comment: @nightowl: I don't know what the zeros represent. If you want colored text, use `\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}`.

Comment: Can you control the specific color this way or its just one set default color when activating a true or false?

Comment: @nightowl: It should be possible to change colors. You should really ask a new question, though -- that way, future users would be able to locate the answers.

Answer (score 3):

The sources of that example are publicly available; for example, chapter and section titles are defined as seen in http://cring.adeel.ru/cring/tree/other/packages.tex

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\LARGE \bfseries \centering}
  {Chapter \ \textbf{\arabic{chapter}}}
  {3pt}
  {}
  [\hrule]
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {\S\arabic{section}}
  {10pt}
  {}
```