# Insert list of figures in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to create a list of all the figures at the end of a document (this I can do) and make it appear in the table of contents?

So in the the table of content there will be a line saying `List of figures ... 19` for example?

Comment: Please, provide also the information about the class you're using.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The List of Figures is produced with `\listoffigures`; you have to manually add it to the table of contents, so it should be preceded by `\cleardoublepage` in order to ensure that the page reference is correct. Uncomment the `\phantomsection` line if you're using `hyperref`:

```
\cleardoublepage
% \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
```

Comment: I prefer loading the `tocbibind` package (or using special class faetures) because the LoF shouldn't be always preceded by a page break if one uses the `article` class.

Comment: This work but is there a way to change the \listfigurename to something else?

Comment: @kasmanit Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc

Comment: @kasmanit That's why I used `\listfigurename`, so that you can change its meaning as outlined in the question which lockstep pointed to.

Comment: Whoever reads this - remember if your document doesn't have chapters (e.g. an `article`) - you'll need to replace `{chapter}` with `{section}` or something similar.

Comment: In case you want to do the same for the tables, use \listtablename and \listoftables instead.

Comment: Why use `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\clearpage`? Is there any difference if you aren't working with a two-sided document?

Comment: @TakingItCasual Maybe you change your mind and decode to go for a two-side document

Answer (score 46):

This answer depends on your document class and some related packages.

- If you are using a standard class you can use the package [`tocbibind`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind)
- If you are using a [KOMA-script class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) you can use the option `listof=totoc`.
- If you want to add the entry manual you can use the command `\addcontentsline`
- If you are using the [class memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) the command `\listoffigures` creates an entry in the table of contents.

Comment: `tocbibind` helped, thanks! Manually with `\addcontentsline` did generate a wrong numbering.

Comment: where do I add the `listof=totoc`? as an option behind `\listoffigures`? (using scrbook)

Comment: @Lilo it's meant to go into `\documentclass[...]`

Comment: @lilo
`\KOMAoption{listof}{totoc}`
`\listoffigures`

Answer (score 1):

There's a really simple way to do this. Maybe the last comment meant that, but I'm not sure.
Change the name of `\listofigures` by using `\renewcommand\listfigurename{}`. So you can easy use `\section{Abbildungsverzeichnis}` to insert the list in your table of contents.

Comment: This is very risky, since it depends on the document class. For example, `report` prints `\listoffigures` as a `\chapter*`, not a `\section`. Moreover, your approach will provide a *numbered* section (not common with the LoF/LoT/ToC front matter). Finally, even if you remove `\listfigurename`, you'll be setting a sectional unit twice with your approach.