# Figures: Can the list of figures be embedded into the table of contents?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

Can the list of figure be embedded in the table of contents for the article class?

I tried a variation of the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48509/insert-list-of-figures-in-the-table-of-contents) but by replacing chapter with section and then tried using chapter.  The only thing that appeared was the list of figures.

To be more clear, I would like for my figures to be combined with the table of contents not a link to the figure sections; that is, if figure 1 is in section 1, the table of contents will look like

```
1 something
   figure 1 caption
```

Figures are setup as

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{}
...
\end{figure}
```

So this is my setup:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{kurier}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[protrusion = true, expansion]{microtype}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{starfont}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}                                                      
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{thmtools}                                                               
%\usepackage{amsthm}                                                                 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin = 0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

%  Figures in TOC                                                                   
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ext@figure{toc}
\makeatother

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Figure~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylen}

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \subfloat[\(L_1\)]{\includegraphics[width = 3.25in]{L1Contour}} &
    \subfloat[\(L_2\)]{\includegraphics[width = 3.25in]{L2Contour}}\\
    \subfloat[\(L_3\)]{\includegraphics[width = 3.25in]{L3Contour}} &
    \subfloat[\(L_4\) and \(L_5\)]{\includegraphics[width = 3.25in]
      {L4L5Contour}}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption[2-D Zero Velocity Surfaces]
  {2-D zero velocity surfaces for the Earth-Moon Lagrange points.}
  \label{fig:2dzerovelocitysurface}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`

Comment: I believe that `tocbibind` is sufficient

Comment: @egreg so `\tableofcontents` will then have the the sections and figures in their respective locations combined into one?  I just tried this setup and it only produced the sections without the figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change the extension of the file in which figures are written, from the deafult `lof` to `toc`; I also used the `tocloft` package to add the word "Figure" before the number for the entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfig}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ext@figure{toc}
\makeatother

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Figure~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftfignumwidth{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section One}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
A
\caption{test figure}
\end{figure}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
A
\caption{another test figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\subfloat[][A subfigure]{A}
\subfloat[][A subfigure]{B}
\caption{test figure with subfigures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using an empty first argument for `\subfloat` and reserving the caption for the second optional argument, subfigures won't be listed.

The placement modifier `[!ht]` was used just for the example; I am not suggesting it should be used in the actual document.

Looking at the preamble added to the question, please notice that you are loading `subfig` twice: the first time without options and the second one with `caption = false` and this produces a clash. Load the package only once. Also notice that `hyperref` must be loaded in last place, just before `hypcap`.

Comment: There is just one problem.  It shows the subfigures in the TOC.  Can it ignore the subfigures and just have the main figure in the TOC?

Comment: @dustin how exactly do you buid your subfigures?

Comment: @dustin I've fixed the code. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I have an option class: `l.41 \usepackage[all]{hypcap}`

Comment: @dustin So? My answer works also when you load `hypcap` with the `all` option. If something is not working for you, please compose a MWE and add it to your question.

Comment: @dustin I already said it. Without seeing a MWE showing the clash, noone can guess where the problem might be. Please compose a MWE and add it to your question.

Comment: @dustin the clash has nothing to do with my code. Please notice that you are loading `subfig` *twice*: the first time *without* options and the second one *with* `caption = false` and this, of course, produces the clash. Load the package only once. Also notice that  `hyperref` must be loaded in last place, just before `hypcap`.

Comment: Are you using the *second* optional argument for the captions and not the first argument? The first optional argument for `\subfloat` must be empty; the second optional argument must contain the caption. Please see my code.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know that had to be the case.

Comment: Nice trick to just change the ToC file extension for figures. However, this also puts the figure headings as level 1 entries into the PDF ToC, so that all following level 2 entry (subsections) are folded under the figure entry instead of the section entry. Any idea to prevent this (maybe just suppress figures in the PDF ToC)?

Comment: Never mind, I have now turned my previous comment into a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120881/how-to-embed-figures-into-the-documents-main-toc-and-pdf-toc-hyperref)