# wrong numbering of listoffigures and listoftables PARTIALLY SOLVED

Tags: table-of-contents

I manage to change the numbering of `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` but including \cleardoublepage but the problem now is that there is a blank page that although is is completely empy, it count for the index . I mean it is printed as:
List of Figures..... X
List of Tables ..... XII

but actually I want

List of Figures..... X
List of Tables ..... XI

I write a MWE but it can not be compiled by you because it is split in different chapters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
\fancyhf{}%
\rfoot{\thepage}%
}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}
   \usepackage{epigraph}
 \newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{{./figuras/}}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{biblio} 
  \usepackage{csquotes}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabu}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}
 \renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\usepackage{graphicx} % figuras

\makeindex
 \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}%[acronym, toc, nonumberlist, shortcuts, xindy=language=spanish-traditional, sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{DRX}{DRX}{Difracción de Rayos X}

 \begin{document}

   \doublespacing
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de Tablas}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Lista de Acrónimos}

 \include{./capitulos/titulo}
 \include{./capitulos/ded}
 \include{./capitulos/resumenes}
 \include{./capitulos/abst}

 \cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\include{./capitulos/tabla}
\cleardoublepage
 \thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de figuras} 
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de tablas} % para que aparezca en el  
 \listoftables
\cleardoublepage
 \thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de Acrónimos}

 \thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
 \include{acronyms}
 \thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
 \include{./capitulos/introduccion}
 \include{./capitulos/Materialesm}
 \include{./capitulos/sintesis}
\include{./capitulos/SBR}
\include{./capitulos/pvdf}
\include{./capitulos/gracias}
\include{./capitulos/bibliog}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are adding the corresponding entries _manually_ with `\addcontentsline` at the same place, so no wonder you get twice the same page number `:-)` See e.g. [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48509)

Comment: @campa I've tried removing either \addcontentsline or \include{./capitulos/tablatlista} unsuccessfuly

Comment: @Leila: All of your content is in the various external files -- your file document does not generate any output

Comment: You edited the question but it's not clearer, actually

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your desired output should be, so I'll try two cases:

**Removing the empty page**

To get the LoF and LoT to be on two successive pages, replace `\cleardoublepage` with `\clearpage`. But without the empty page, the LoT will be printed on the backside of the LoF if you print double sided.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
\fancyhf{}%
\rfoot{\thepage}%
}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}
   \usepackage{epigraph}
 \newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{{./figuras/}}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{biblio} 
  \usepackage{csquotes}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabu}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}
 \renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\usepackage{graphicx} % figuras

\makeindex
 \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}%[acronym, toc, nonumberlist, shortcuts, xindy=language=spanish-traditional, sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{DRX}{DRX}{Difracción de Rayos X}

 \begin{document}

   \doublespacing
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de Tablas}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Lista de Acrónimos}


\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
 \thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de figuras} 
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de tablas} % para que aparezca en el  
 \listoftables


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Manipulating the page number**

If you just want the page number of the LoT to be one less, you can use `\addtocounter{page}{-1}`. The page number given on the page of the LoT and in the ToC will be 4 (in my example below), but physically it will be the 5th page.

**Please do not use this unless you are printing onesided and throw away the empty paper sheets. Because even if a page is empty, it is a page and should be counted.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
\fancyhf{}%
\rfoot{\thepage}%
}

\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}}
   \usepackage{epigraph}
 \newcommand\blankpage{%
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
\newpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{{./figuras/}}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{biblio} 
  \usepackage{csquotes}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabu}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}
 \renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}
\usepackage{graphicx} % figuras

\makeindex
 \usepackage[toc]{glossaries}%[acronym, toc, nonumberlist, shortcuts, xindy=language=spanish-traditional, sanitize=none]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{DRX}{DRX}{Difracción de Rayos X}

 \begin{document}

   \doublespacing
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Lista de Tablas}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{Lista de Acrónimos}


\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
 \thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de figuras} 
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta pagina
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lista de tablas} % para que aparezca en el  
 \listoftables


\end{document}
```

[image]