# Problem with aknowledgement, etc in Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am using document class report. I have some pages like abstract, acknowledgements, dedication which appear before table of contents

As I saw in the following page 
[Insert list of figures in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48509/insert-list-of-figures-in-the-table-of-contents)

I need to add

```
   \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

to my code.

I have the following code

```
      \pagenumbering{roman} 
      \setcounter{page}{2}
      \include{Abstract}
      \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
       \include{Dedication}
       \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
       \include{Acknowledgements}
       \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}


       %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tableofcontents}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
         \include{Abbreviations}
         \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}

        \pagenumbering{arabic}
        \setcounter{page}{1}

        \include{Introduction}
        .....
```

Note that I tried adding \addcontentsline  before and after the include, with the same results.

I also use the following:

```
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
      colorlinks,
      citecolor=black,
      filecolor=black,
      linkcolor=black,
      urlcolor=black}
```

I have three problems:

1- The above code adds the pages abstract, acknowledgements, dedication to the table of contents, but when I click, they don't take me to the right page.

2- I am not able to add table of contents to table of contents.

3- For some reason, Abbreviations (which has two pages) is listed after the chapter 1 in table of contents. When I click it, it only takes me to page 2 of abbreviation.

Also is there a way to hide the chapter name from being displayed in the dedication page?

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand point 2: when you read the table of contents, you want to know which page it will be found? :–)

Comment: @Bernard I mean, how can I add the entry "table of contents" to show in the actual table of contents ! It is a requirement by my college

Comment: Off-topic: Since the instruction `\pagenumbering{arabic}` is provided, the follow-up instruction `\setcounter{page}{1}` shouldn't  be needed.

Comment: You can do that with the `tocbibind` package.

Comment: @Mico: ;o) – I definitely should look more carefully at what's posted…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- The above code adds the pages abstract, acknowledgements, dedication to the table of contents, but when I click, they don't take me to the right page.

You need to insert a `\phantomsection` instruction immediately after `\chapter*{Abstract}`, `chapter*{Dedication}`, `\chapter*{Acknowledgments}`, etc. This should happen, obviously, *inside* the files `Abstract.tex`, `Dedication.tex`, `Acknowledgments.tex`, etc.

> 2- I am not able to add table of contents to table of contents.

I suggest you load the `tocbibind` package with the option `notindex`:

```
\usepackage[notindex]{tocbibind}
```

This setup also provides for insertion of entries for the list of figures, the list of tables, and the bibliography in the table of contents. I.e., you will no longer need to provide the instruction `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}`.

Of course, if your document does contain an (unnumbered) index and if you wish to show this (unnumbered) entity, you can omit the option `notindex`.

> 3- For some reason, Abbreviations (which has two pages) is listed after the chapter 1 in table of contents. When I click it, it only takes me to page 2 of abbreviation.

This is happening because the instruction `\addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}` occurs too late, *viz.*, after both pages of abbreviations have been generated by LaTeX. I suggest you move `\addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}` into file `Abbreviations.tex` and execute it right after `\chapter*{Abbreviations}`.

You should probably also insert the instruction `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`) immediately before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Comment: Just a clarification: currently neither the bibliography nor the contents appear in the table of contents. If I need to show both of them, I should just use  \usepackage{tocbibind}?  I want to show both of them but without a chapter number to appear on bibiliography

Comment: When I use the command suggested and run latex, I get the error can not execute command doc oped ...... But when I comment it out I am able to run the file without problems. I am using win 7 and TexNicCenter

Comment: @MelanieA - TeXnicCenter is just a front-end. Which TeX distribution to you employ? If you happen to use MikTeX, do you know how to install a "missing package"? (It looks like you may not have installed the `tocbibind` package by default.)

Comment: @MelanieA - Indeed, if you want to show the (unnumbered) bibliography in the table of contents, do omit the `notbib` option.

Comment: Thanks :) Now I can see contents and bib in table of contents. Could you please help with the other two issues?

Comment: is there a way that I could remove the chapter heading from my dedication page without disrupting toc?  It works, but visually it does not look good. Currently I have \chapter*{Dedication}
\addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{Dedication}