# Thesis table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I am using a book class to write my PHD thesis, I have a problem with the front matter content and the content table, for example when I compile, the general introduction page header contains: CHAPITRE.0 LISTE DES ABREVIATIONS tha same thing happens in the general conclusion CHAPITRE.2 NAME OF CHAPTER 2. It seems that when I used `\chapter*{general intoduction}`  (for section without numbering) for the general introduction or the general conclusion the name of the last chapter appears in the header of the next chapter.

what is the right way write a Table of Contents (Contents, Abbreviations, Symboles,Table of Figures,Table of Tables, General Introduction, Chapter1,...,General conclusion, Appendix) and why the Table of Figures and Table of Tables do not appear in the Contents in my case?

MWE:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,french,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm,top=2.2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
% write arabic-------------------------
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
%Table Caption-------------------------
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
\def\frenchtablename{Tableau}
%Table-----------------------
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%----------------------------
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%Dummy text--
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}

%------------------------------------
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
%------------------------------------
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor=cyan]{hyperref}
\setcitestyle{square,aysep={},yysep={,}}

% footers------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[EC]{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}

%--Main body--
\begin{document}
%--- PAGE DE GARDE --
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{-2.5cm}
\begin{center}
{\bf  République Démocratique et Populaire
\\ Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur et de la
Recherche Scientifique} \vspace{0.5cm}\\
 {\bf {\large Université}}\\
{\bf Faculté Des Sciences et de la Technologie} \\
{\bf Département d'Automatique}\\
Laboratoire \vspace{0.5cm}

{\bf{\huge {Thèse}}} Présentée par: \vspace{0.5cm}
\\{\huge {\textbf{Personne}}}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\\ {\bf \large En vue de l'obtention du diplôme de Doctorat 3\textsuperscript{ème} cycle LMD en automatique}

\vspace{0.2cm}
{\large {\bf Option: {\it Traitement de signal et d'image (TSI)
}}}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Titre de la thèse:
%=============================================================================================
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
{\setlength {\fboxsep }{6pt} \fbox{\begin{minipage}{16cm}
\vspace{0.5cm}
%
\begin{center}\huge{\textbf{Title}}\end{center} \vspace{0.8cm}
\end{minipage}}}
%
\end{center} \vspace{0.5cm}
\end{center}
%==============================================================================
\vspace{1.0cm}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
 Promotion : Octobre 2019.
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%--remerciment---
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\bf \Large \it $\divideontimes$ $\mathcal{R}$emerciements
$\divideontimes$}
\end{center}\vspace{3cm}

\lipsum[2-4]

\end{titlepage}
\frontmatter

%-------------------------------------Content------------------------------------------
\dominitoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Table des matières}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

%-----------------------------------Symbole content------------------------------------
\chapter{Liste des symboles}
%\addstarredchapter{Liste des symboles}
%\minitoc
\begin{tabular}{ll}
            $C_a$ & Concentration artérielle totale d'O\textsubscript{2}\\
            $C_p$ & Concentration d'O\textsubscript{2} capillaire de plasma\\
            $C_T$ & Concentration totale d'O\textsubscript{2} capillaire\\
            $E_n$ & Fraction d'extraction nette d'O\textsubscript{2}\\
            $E(f)$ & Fraction d'extraction unidirectionnelle d'O\textsubscript{2}\\
            $E_0$ & Fraction d'extraction d'oxygène au repos\\
            $f$ & Flux sanguin cérébral normalisé\\
            $F_{in}$  & Flux entrant dans le tissu\\
            $F_{out}$ & Flux sortant du tissu\\
            $h(t)$ & Distribution de temps de transit capillaire $t$\\
            $K_l$ & Paramètre de débit qui gouverne la livraison d'O\textsubscript{2} dans les tissus et\\
            \ & ainsi définie le taux de métabolisme oxydatif maximale possible\\
            $\epsilon$ & Efficacité du métabolisme d'O\textsubscript{2} (la fraction de molécules d'O\textsubscript{2} extraites\\
             & qui sont métabolisées)\\
            $V$ & Fraction de volume de sang\\
            $V_0$ & Fraction du volume sanguin au repos\\
            $v$ & Volume sanguin cérébral normalisé\\
            $V_a$ & Volume artériel\\
            $V_e$ & Volume capillaire\\
            $V_v$& Volume veineux\\
            $q$ & Contenu de désoxyhémoglobine total normalisé\\
            $P$ & Pression dans le compartiment veineux\\
            $P_{mixed}$ & Pression du sang veineux mêlé en aval de l'élément de tissu\\
            $\tau_0$ & Temps de transit moyen à travers le compartiment\\
            $\alpha$ & Paramètre de Grrub\\
            $s,\ s_f$ & Signal induisant l'augmentation de flux.\\
            $\tau_s$ & Constante de temps d'élimination du signal\\
            $\tau_f$ & Constante de temps pour la rétroaction d'autorégulation du FSC.\\
            $\kappa_s$ & Inverse de la constante de temps d'élimination du signal\\
            $\kappa_f$ & Inverse de la constante de temps d'auto-régulation du système par \textit{feed-back}\\
                       & à partir du FSC\\
            $OGI$ & Indice de l'oxygène au glucose\\
            CMRO\textsubscript{2} & Taux métabolique cérébrale d'oxygène\\
            CMR\textsubscript{Glc} & Taux métabolique cérébrale du glucose\\

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
$u$ & Activité neuronale\\
            $u_e$ & Activité neuronale excitatrice\\
            $u_i$ & Activité neuronale inhibitrice\\
            $g_e$ & Consommation de glucose due à l'activité excitatrice\\
            $g_i$ & Consommation de glucose due à l'activité inhibitrice\\          
            $g$ & Consommation totale de glucose\\          
            $m_e$ & Consommation d'oxygène due à l'activité excitatrice\\
            $m_i$ & Consommation d'oxygène due à l'activité inhibitrice\\
            $m$ & Consommation totale d'oxygène\\   
            $s_e$ & Signal induisant de consommation de glucose due à l'activité neuronale excitatrice\\
            $s_i$ & Signal induisant de consommation de glucose due à l'activité neuronale inhibitrice\\
            $\tau_e$ & Efficacité de consommation de glucose due à l'activité neuronale excitatrice\\ 
            $\tau_i$ & Efficacité de consommation de glucose due à l'activité neuronale inhibitrice\\ 
            $x_0$ & Fraction du glucose suivant le chemin glycogenolitique au repos\\
            $\gamma$ & Rapport entre l'activité synaptique excitatrice et inhibitrice à l'état initial\\
            $x$ &Fraction de glucose suivant la voie glycogenolitique\\
            $c$ & Inclinaison de fonction sigmoïde (\eqref{Equat2.45})\\
            $d$ & Pente de fonction sigmoïde (\eqref{Equat2.45})\\
            $\delta_e$ & Retard après le stimulus et avant la réponse de consommation de glucose due à\\
            & l'activité excitatrice commence\\
            $\delta_i$ & Retard après le stimulus et avant la réponse de consommation de glucose due à\\
            & l'activité inhibitrice commence\\
            $\delta_f$ & Retard entre l'activité neuronale et la réponse du FSC\\
            $y(t)$ & Signal BOLD\\
            $\mathbf{x}$ & Vecteur\\
            $\mathbf{x}_k$ & Variable d'état discrète à l'instant discret $k$\\
            $\mathbf{x}(t)$ & Variable d'état continu à l'instant $t$\\
            $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ & Estimation de $\mathbf{x}$ \\
            $\bm{\theta}$ & Vecteur de paramètres de modèle\\
            $\mathbf{y}_k$ & Observations discrètes\\
            $\mathbf{f}(.), \mathbf{f_d}(.)$ & Équation d'état \\
            $\mathbf{h}(.)$ & Équation de mesure\\
            $p(\mathbf{x})$, & Densité de probabilité de variable aléatoire $\mathbf{x}$\\
            $p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{y})$ & Densité de probabilité conditionnelle de $\mathbf{x}$ étant donné $\mathbf{y}$ \\
            $\mathbf{y}_{1:k}$ & Ensemble contenant les vecteurs $\mathbf{y}_1,...,\mathbf{y}_k$\\
            diag($\mathbf{A}$) & Diagonal de la matrice $\mathbf{A}$\\
            diag($a_1,...,a_n$) & Matrice diagonale avec des valeurs $a_1,...,a_n$\\
            Tria($\mathbf{A}$) & Triangularisation de la matrice\\
             exp(.) & Exponentielle ou exponentielle matricielle\\
            $\mathbf{A}^T$ & Matrice transposée\\
            $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ & Matrice inverse\\
            $\mathbf{I}$ & Matrice identité\\
            $\E[\mathbf{x}]$ & Espérance de $\mathbf{x}$\\
            $\E[\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{y}]$ & Espérance de $\mathbf{x}$ étant donné $\mathbf{y}$\\
\end{tabular}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-----------------------------------Symbole content---------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Liste des abréviations}
%\addstarredchapter{Liste des abréviations}
%\minitoc
\begin{tabular}{ll}
            SNC  & Système Nerveux Central\\
            SNP  & Système Nerveux Périphérique\\
            LCR  & Liquide Céphalo-Rachidien\\
            SRM  & Spectroscopie par Résonance Magnétique.\\
            VSD  & Voltage Sensitive Dyes\\
            TDM  & Tomodensitométrie\\
            IRM  & Imagerie par Résonance Magnétique\\
            TEP  & Tomographie par Émission de Positons\\
            FDG  & Fluro-Deoxy-D-Glucose\\
            IRMf & Imagerie par Résonance Magnétique fonctionnelle.\\
            BOLD & Blood Oxygen Level Dependent\\
            EEG  & Électroencéphalographie\\

            MEG  & Magnétoencéphalographie\\

            SQUID  & Superconducting Quantum Interference Devices\\
            CMR\textsubscript{Glc} & Cerebral Metabolic Rate of Glucose Consumption.\\
            CMRO\textsubscript{2} & Cerebral Metabolic Rate of Oxygen Consumption.\\
            FSC & Flux Sanguin Cérébral\\   
            CBF & Cerebral Blood Flow\\
            VSC & Volume Sanguin Cérébral\\
            CBV & Cerebral Blood Volume\\
            HbR & Hémoglobine Réduite\\ 
            ATP & Adénosine Triphosphate\\
            FEO & Fraction d'Extraction nette d'O\textsubscript{2}\\
            FRH & Fonction de Réponse Hémodynamique\\               HRF & Hemodynamic Response Function\\
            GRE & Gradient Echo\\   
            rCBF & régional Cerebral Blood Flow\\
            FSCr & Flux Sanguin Cérébral régional\\
            MHM & Metabolic Hemodynamic Model\\
            RMN & Résonance Magnétique Nucléaire\\  
            OGI & Oxygen to Glucose Index\\
            GABA & Gamma-Aminobutyric Acid\\
            MMC & Modèle de Markov Caché\\
            HMM & Hidden Markov Model\\
            EDO & Équation Différentielle ordinaire\\   

\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
            CKF & Cubature Kalman Filter.\\
            EKF & Extended Kalman Filter.\\
            UKF & Unscented Kalman Filter.\\
            SVD & Singular Value Decomposition\\
            SCKF & Square root Cubature Kalamn Filter\\          
            LL & Local Linéarisation\\
            EMV  & Estimateur du Maximum de Vraisemblance.\\
            MIF & Matrice d'Information de Fisher\\
            LAPACK  & Linaer Algebra Package\\
            PQS  & Programmation Quadratique Séquentielle\\
            SQP & Sequential Quadratic programming\\
            LB  & Lower Bound\\
            UB  & Upper Bound\\
            LLF & Local linearization Filter\\
            SPM & Statistical Parametric Mapping\\
            FSL  & Functional MRI of the brain Softaware Library\\

            TR  & Temps de Répétition\\
            TA  & Temps d'Acquisition\\
            FOV & Field Of View\\
            EPI & Echo-Planar Imaging\\
            MNI & Montreal Neurological Institut\\
            RSB & Rapport Signal sur Bruit\\
            FWHM & Full Width at Half Maximum\\             
\end{tabular}   
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}\markboth{\bf \footnotesize{\emph{Introduction générale}}}{}
\addstarredchapter{Introduction générale}
\minitoc
\lipsum[2-10]

\chapter{Organisation structurelle et fonctionnelle du cerveau}
\label{chap:Chapitre1}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc
\section{Introduction}

\section{Éléments de neuroanatomie}

\subsection{Système nerveux}

\subsection{Cellules nerveuses}

\subsubsection{Neurone}

\subsubsection{Cellules gliales}

\section{Représentation en coupe du cerveau}

\section{Structure et organisation du cerveau}

\subsection{Cortex cérébral}

\section{Métabolisme}

\section{Neuroimagerie structurelle}

\subsection{Radiographie}

\subsection{Scanner X}

\subsection{Imagerie par résonance magnétique (IRM)}

\section{Neuroimagerie fonctionnelle}

\subsection{Imagerie métabolique}

\subsubsection{Tomographie par émission de positons TEP}

\subsubsection{Imagerie par résonance magnétique fonctionnelle (IRMf)}

\subsection{Imagerie électrique}
\subsubsection{Électroencéphalographie (EEG)}

\subsubsection{Magnétoencéphalographie (MEG)}


\section{Conclusion}


%*****************************************************************************************************
%                                          CHAPITRE II
%*****************************************************************************************************

\chapter{Modélisation de l'activité neuronale}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc
\section{Introduction}

\section{Modèles physiologiques de la réponse hémodynamique}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
%                      Conclusion générale
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter*{Conclusion générale}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion générale}\markboth{\bf \footnotesize{\emph{Conclusion générale}}}{}
\addstarredchapter{Conclusion générale}
\minitoc
\lipsum[2-10]

%--------------------------------------------------------------
%                             Annexe
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Annexe}
%\chapter{Publications}
%\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={},width=\textwidth]{Boureghda2018.pdf}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Annexe}
\chapter{Dérivation de l'équation différentielle du second ordre pour la consommation de glucose normalisée}

\chapter{Déduction de la dérivée du gain du SCKF}

\chapter{Quelques dérivées utilisées dans les développements théoriques}

\section{Dérivée de la norme d'un vecteur}

\section{Dérivée de la k-ième colonne d'une matrice}

\chapter{Tester la méthode differetiated QR sur des exemples numériques}

\section{Exemple numérique 1}

\section{Exemple numérique 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you use packages for abbreviations, glossar etc? Maybe that would both help with the layout problem and with the generation of these indexes. i used nomenclature for abbreviations.

Comment: This working example is far from being minimal.

Comment: why the name of the last chapter appears in the header of the next chapter in case of using section without numbering?

Comment: The incorrect chapter headings will be because of some command you've issued.  Without making your example *minimal*, I don't foresee someone wanting to wade into your code to figure out why it happened.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 for help in making this more minimal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right/best way, but this gets rid of the Chapter 0 issue (and doesn't give them chapter numbers because you're still in the \frontmatter.

```
\chapter*{Liste des symboles}
```

```
\chapter*{Liste des abréviations}
```

Following the advice here ([Insert list of figures in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48509/insert-list-of-figures-in-the-table-of-contents)), the following adds the ToF and ToT into the contents.

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables
```