# ToC bibliography section hyperref doesn't work with sectsty and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, hyperref, sectsty

I need section titles to be uppercase. I've done this with `sectsty`, but have recently discovered an issue that it causes. In the table of contents, clicking on "References" does not bring me to the section, and there's the following warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{section*.2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

For the LoF I can use `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`, but when the bibliography is empty `\printbibliography` doesn't output a section, which would break this method (unless there's way of detecting if a `\printbibliography` command outputs nothing).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
    \sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\scshape\MakeUppercase} % Removing this fixes the problem

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{2people,
    author = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2},
    title = {Some Other Thing},
    date = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage\section{First}
\begin{figure}[H]\caption{Caption \parencite{2people}}\end{figure}
\clearpage\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\clearpage\listoffigures
%\cleardoublepage % Using these instead of tocbibind fixes the LoF link in the ToC
%\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
%\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: It won't work. You are putting the \MakeUppercase around the whole argument, and inside \MakeUppercase hyperref doesn't set an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way of capitalizing the section titles that doesn't disrupt `hyperref` can be used:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\@oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{
    % \text_uppercase will replace \tl_upper_case in later l3token versions
    \tl_set:Nx\@section_upper{\cs_if_exist:NTF{\text_uppercase:n}
        {\text_uppercase:n{#3}}{\tl_upper_case:n{#3}}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\@oldsection*{\@section_upper}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
            {\@oldsection{\@section_upper}}
            {\@oldsection[#2]{\@section_upper}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

At least for the `article` class, you can style the section titles directly without `sectsty`. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% Make section/subsection text size same as normal text
\patchcmd{\section}{\Large}{\normalsize}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\large}{\normalsize}{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Capitalize section titles
\let\@oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{
    % \text_uppercase will replace \tl_upper_case in later l3token versions
    \tl_set:Nx\@section_upper{\cs_if_exist:NTF{\text_uppercase:n}
        {\text_uppercase:n{#3}}{\tl_upper_case:n{#3}}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
        {\@oldsection*{\@section_upper}}
        {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
            {\@oldsection{\@section_upper}}
            {\@oldsection[#2]{\@section_upper}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Capitalize section titles in ToC (/a/156917)
\let\@oldcontentsline\contentsline
\def\contentsline#1#2{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\l@section
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\@oldcontentsline{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
    {\@oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{2people,
    author = {John Smith1 and Alex Smith2},
    title = {Some Other Thing},
    date = {1971}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage\section{First Section}
\begin{figure}[H]\caption{caption text \parencite{2people}}\end{figure}
\clearpage\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\clearpage\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) [explained in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552587/toc-bibliography-section-hyperref-doesnt-work-with-sectsty-and-biblatex#comment1395240_552587) the `\MakeUppercase` at the end of `\sectionfont` applies to its complete argument and effectively disables `hyperref`'s anchor. That's why you need manual `\phantomsection`s.

You could define a new heading type `mybibintoc`

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{mybibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

and use that `\printbibliography[heading=mybibintoc]`.

This redefines the bibliography heading to automatically include `\phantomsection`. With that definition the link anchor will point to after the heading though, which you may find undesirable.

You could switch the order round a bit and move the `\section*{#1}%` to after `\addcontentsline`, but then the label could again attach to the wrong thing. If you are starting a new page before the bibliography anyway, the safest would be to include the `\clearpage` in the heading definition. Then the anchor is always good.

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{mybibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\scshape\MakeUppercase} % Removing this fixes the problem

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\defbibheading{mybibintoc}[\refname]{%
  \clearpage
  \phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\lorem}{lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\newcommand*{\lllorem}{\lorem\ \lorem\ \lorem}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage\section{First}
\begin{figure}[H]\caption{Caption \parencite{sigfridsson}}\end{figure}
%\clearpage\section*{Second}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Second}
\lipsum[1-3] 
\lllorem\ \lllorem\ \lllorem\ Lorem.
\printbibliography [heading=mybibintoc]
%\clearpage\listoffigures
%\cleardoublepage % Using these instead of tocbibind fixes the LoF link in the ToC
%\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
%\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're using just `\clearpage`, while in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48511 `\cleardoublepage` is used. Is there a difference when used in a single-sided document?

Comment: @TakingItCasual Mhh, I didn't think about `\cleardoublepage`. I just took what you had in the MWE. In a `oneside`d document there is no difference between `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`, though. In a `twoside`d document the question is if you want the new page to start on an odd page (when you would use `\cleardoublepage`) or if you don't care about odd or even (use `\clearpage`). ...

Comment: ... It is only imperative to use `\cleardoublepage` if the sectioning command would issue it itself. If you had a two-sided `book` and would typeset the heading with `\chapter*` you could get a bad link (to the empty page) with `\clearpage` if the previous chapter ends on an odd page, there you need `\cleardoublepage`. But in your example you always force page breaks manually anyway, so it shouldn't matter.