# How to include figure list and table list in the index of my article?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to include the figure list and table list in the index of my article, similarly with others numbered sections. But, when I use the code below nothing happened. There are a way to do it?

```
    \begin{document}
    
%-------------index--------------------
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\break

%---------figure list------
\listoffigures

\break

%---------table list------
\listoftables

\break
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Insert list of figures in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48509/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: It works, thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long way would be use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listof...}` at the appropriate place.

If you use KOMA, you're lucky, because you can just do: `\documentclass[listof=totoc]{KOMA-Class}`