Why the difference in headwidth of header/footer in the bibliography page?
I am trying to write a document in latex. Document class is report, using fancyhdr for header and footer. The geometry seems to be wrong because the header/footer width where the \begin{thebibliography} starts has been stretched when compared to previous page.
I am using pdflatex to compile the document.
Here is the MWE.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}
\textheight=235mm
\textwidth=145mm
\topmargin=0mm
\headheight=0mm
\headsep=0mm
\oddsidemargin=15mm
\evensidemargin=15mm
\usepackage[]{setspace}
\singlespacing
\setstretch{1}
\usepackage{cite}
\linespread{1.3}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{\LARGE References}
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} %clear everything.
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} %0pt for no rule, 2pt thicker etc...
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
    \fancyfoot[l]{FOOT LEFT}
    \fancyfoot[c]{FOOT CENTER}
    \fancyfoot[r]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[r]{HEAD RIGHT}
}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in,headsep=10mm}
\section{CONTENT}

\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{7}
    \bibitem{1} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM ONE

    \bibitem{2} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM TWO

    \bibitem{3} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM THREE

    \bibitem{4} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM FOUR
\newpage
    \bibitem{5} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM FIVE

    \bibitem{6} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM SIX

    \bibitem{7} BIBLIOGRAPHY ITEM SEVEN
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


I tried to use \usepackage{afterpage} and then \clearpage with setting the \newgeometry which does not seem to help. Is there any workaround or what's causing this? Any help is much appreciated.

Sorry, but you should clear-out your document preamble first. For example, loading geometry with setting-up margins but afterwards changing almost all layout lengths and then again using \newgeometry does not make any sense. Similar for your sequence of \singlespacing, \setstretch, \linespread. Also you are adding an unwanted space into \captionsenglish. Also using \LARGE in \bibname is not recommended, because it influences every usage of \bibname not only the heading of the bibliographies.

Off-topic: Your \addcontentsline is too late to add the beginning (aka first page) of the table of contents to the table of contents. → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48512/277964 for better solution, if you really see a sense in doing so — I don't.

IMHO this is a kind of XY problem. Please explain as precisely as possible what you are trying to achieve instead of just showing your problem with your attempted solution. For example: If your want different margins for the title page, please tell us which margins should be used at the title pages and which at the other pages. If you want something different, tell us what you want. And remove everything that is not related to your question from your example.

I'm not sure, that I've understood, what you want. But your main problem is surely the:
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} %clear everything.
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}
    \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}

Here you are increasing the \headwidth (twice) with every activation of pagestyle plain. Here an example, that illustrated this better:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{2cm}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
The first page with page style plain activated by \verb|\chapter|.

\chapter*{A chapter}
\pagestyle{plain}
The second page with page style plain activated by \verb|\chapter*| and an
explicit \verb|\pagestyle{plain}|.

\chapter{A chapter}
\pagestyle{plain}
The second page with page style plain activated by \verb|\chapter| and an
explicit \verb|\pagestyle{plain}|.

\end{document}


As you can see, every \pagestyle{plain} increases the width head width.
But the \thispagestyle{plain} implicitly used by \chapter*{…} and \chapter{…} (note thebibliography also uses \chapter*{\refname}) also locally activate the page style:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{2cm}%
}

%\AddToHook{env/thebibliography/begin}{\addtolength{\headwidth}{-2cm}}

\usepackage{mwe}

\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
The first page with page style plain activated by \verb|\chapter|.

\clearpage

One more page.

\chapter*{A chapter}
The second page with page style plain activated by \verb|\chapter*| and an
explicit \verb|\pagestyle{plain}|.

\chapter{One more}

\end{document}


Here the head width of the \chapter*{…} and \chapter{…} pages is different from that of the second page, despite both are using the same page style. This is because of \thispagestyle{plain} in \chapter*{…} and \chapter{…} and the special processing of \thispagestyle{…}.
So if you want a single increase of the head width somewhere in your document, just add only one \addtolength{\headwidth}{…} at that point, but don't add it to the definition of the page style:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm,
bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%clear everything.  
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \fancyfoot[l]{FOOT LEFT}%
  \fancyfoot[c]{FOOT CENTER}%
  \fancyfoot[r]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[r]{HEAD RIGHT}%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\pagestyle{plain}
% Either:
% \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}% Use the wider head from the first page.
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\Blindtext[8]

\chapter{Again plain}
% Or:
\addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}% use the wider head from this page.
\Blindtext[8]

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \bibitem{test} Example \blindtext
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

or make sure, that this page style is never used with \thispagestyle{…}, e.g., use a different page style for the document (because plain is used implicitly):
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm,
bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%clear everything.  
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \fancyfoot[l]{FOOT LEFT}%
  \fancyfoot[c]{FOOT CENTER}%
  \fancyfoot[r]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[r]{HEAD RIGHT}%
}

\fancypagestyle{document}{%
  \fancyhf{}%clear everything.
  \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \fancyfoot[l]{FOOT LEFT}%
  \fancyfoot[c]{FOOT CENTER}%
  \fancyfoot[r]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhead[r]{HEAD RIGHT}%
}
  

\usepackage{mwe}

\pagestyle{document}% Use this only once!!!
\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}

\Blindtext[8]

\chapter*{A chapter}
\Blindtext[8]

\chapter{Empty header and footer}
\pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}

\Blindtext[8]

\chapter{Again plain}
\pagestyle{plain}
\Blindtext[8]

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
  \bibitem{test} Example \blindtext
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

Now, after removing \addtolength{\headwidth}{.7cm} from page style plain and therefore not using it in the special page style of \thispagestyle{plain}, everything is fine:

