TOC starts on page 2 but it says it starts on page 3
I am trying to fix my TOC (in German its "Inhaltsverzeichnis"). It starts on page 2 (roman format) and is 2 pages long (end is on page 3). in the TOC it says it starts on page 3.
Normally it should say that it starts on page 2...
Maybe somone knows what is wrong?
Thanks for your help!!
![here you can see that the TOC starts on page 2 but it says it starts on page 3]
Sorry, i forgot the code... that is my code that i wrote with help of chatgpt and the internet (its my first time use LaTeX so i commented a lot)

Guess: you are manually adding the Inhaltsverzeichnis to the toc and you do so after \tableofcontents?

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

It looks very odd to put a toc entry below the heading "Toc". Who should ever look up the toc page there?

Without code I would guess, that you've added a \addcontentsline at the wrong place. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48512/277964 for better solutions to add entries of ToC, LoF, LoT to the ToC. But I agree with Ulrike: Adding a ToC entry for the ToC is useless and does not make any sense and should be avoided. So you should do this only if you are really required to do it.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes exactly

@UlrikeFischer i dont understand either... my professor wants it

Please don't post images of code. Post it as text

Put \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}} after \tableofcontents and everything should work (needs 3 compilations).

@Skillmon thank you very much!! It worked!

The following shows a rather simple minded way to get the ToC at the correct spot in your ToC and with the correct page number. This approach needs at least 3 typesetting runs to show correct results, and only yields correct results if the ToC entry of the ToC is on the first page of your ToC).
Instead of \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis} put \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}} after \tableofcontents and you're good to go.
The following is a minimal document showcasing that (I don't see the point in retyping your preamble):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\title{This is a title}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}}

\duckument
\duckument
\duckument
\duckument
\duckument
\duckument
\end{document}



thank you very much!!! It worked
