# How to change Table of Contents title from "Contents" to X using memoir?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the title of ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc)

The default Table of Contents title is "Contents". How would I change "Contents" to something else, e.g., "Chapters"? I'm using the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 3):

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{whatever}
```

Comment: Thanks for the headsup. I spend quite a while unsuccessfully searching for the answer among all the TOC-related questions I could find, both yesterday and today. I wonder if you could point me the specific reference? Not as sharp as I used to be, so probably missed it. Thanks.

Comment: I found it. I guess. Different class. Will study. Apologize for taking up bandwidth.

Comment: is this compatible with the tocloft package? I tried the very same line after including the package, but to no avail.

Comment: @shuhalo --- Yes. If you can't get it to work then you should post a new question with an example code that reproduces the problem.