# Customizing the style of the "Table of Contents" title

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I used `titlesec` for customizing chapter titles. How can I put the *Table of contents* title **above** the horizontal line?

(I am trying to customize the place of the title, not the title) Added figure is the result I get, from my existing code.

[image: How can i take the Table of contents title above the line?]

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \large\thechapter}
{2ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filleft}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{120pt}{6pt}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to change the title of toc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc)?

Comment: I tried this answer before, it doesn't work for me. I can change the title to "Table of Contents" from "Contents" but I cannot place it above the line as shown in the figure.

Comment: @user47278 Yes, I've voted for re-opening the question.

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for a solution for 2 days, I read documentation and checked questions. Still I cannot worked a solution for this problem.

Comment: @SahikaKoyun I already have the answer, but cannot post it while the question is closed :(

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Is there any other way I can see your answer :(

Comment: @SahikaKoyun In the meantime (while the question is reopened), here's the code you need: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\large}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \large\thechapter}
  {2ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filleft}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\bfseries\large}
  {\titlerule}
  {-7ex}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase}[\vspace{5ex}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{120pt}{6pt}` (sorry about the poor formatting, but comments don't allow nicer code formatting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your current settings, The rule is placed above the chapter title and below the string "Chapter #", for numbered chapters. You need a different specification for unnumbered chapters (such as the ToC), to make the rule appear below the title; this can be achieved using another `\titleformat` command with the `numberless` key:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\large}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \large\thechapter}
  {2ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filleft}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\bfseries\large}
  {\titlerule}
  {-7ex}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase}[\vspace{5ex}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{120pt}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC:

[image]

An image of a numbered chapter:

[image]