# How can I change the specific TOC of my .tex?

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to change the name of my tables of contents, and I cannot apply with this preface:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,tikz,border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
...
```

I'm using this commands:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{article}{Lista de figuras}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{article}{Lista de tablas} 
\listoftables
```

Obviously, the command \addcontentsline{toc}{article}{Lista de tablas} cannot change any name like "Lista de figuras".

Also, I should like to add the last contents in the principal table of contents with the respective number.

Comment: seems like a duplicate of [How to change the title of ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28516)

Answer (score 3):

See [How to change the title of ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc).

Using babel, it is good to use the `\addto\captions<language>` to replace the title of the TOC or the other lists.  This maintains language compatibility.  `hyperref` was added (with draft option, if you aren't using it already, to minimize the changes introduced) to give the `\phantomsection` command, which allows you to cite the other lists in your TOC.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,tikz,border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref} % Used to allow \phantomsection

\addto\captionsspanish{% Replace "spanish" with the language you use
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
        {\'Indice Completa}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\section{Section One}
\begin{figure}\caption{A Figure}\label{one}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A Table}\label{two}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of sample code]