# Rename ToC, List of Figures, References

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to know how to rename the standard list of figures, table of contents, and references. What I saw so far relying on `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{name}` did not work so far.

Here's the list of preambles I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\newenvironment{remark}{\par\mbox{}\par\noindent{\bfseries             \emph{Remark}\/}:\normalfont}{\par}
\newenvironment{defin}{\par\mbox{}\par\noindent\bfseries \emph{\Pointinghand\     }\normalfont}{\par}
\setcounter{toc**strong text**depth}{2} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, a4paper=true, pdfstartview=FitV,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\setstretch{1.0} %vertical stretch
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont       = AvenirNextRoundedPro-Bold.otf , ItalicFont     =AvenirNextRoundedPro-Italic.otf]{AvenirNextRoundedPro-Reg.otf}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{ hidelinks, }
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %Adds "References" to toc
\usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\huge}{\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{1ex}{\vspace{1ex}\filright}[\vspace{0.5ex}\titlerule]
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox} \makeatletter \patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{} \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{2em}{6em}} \let\l@table\l@figure  \makeatother % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em - for list of figures and tables
\usepackage{background} \definecolor{textcolor}{HTML}{000000}             \newcommand\Text{c\quad o\quad n\quad f\quad i\quad d\quad e\quad n\quad t\quad i\quad a\quad l} \SetBgColor{textcolor}\SetBgOpacity{0.3}\SetBgAngle{90}         \SetBgPosition{current page.center} \SetBgVshift{-0.33\textwidth} \SetBgScale{1.8}         \SetBgContents{\sffamily\Text} %for confidential
```

I also use TexMaker. I do not know how relevant it is, but here my document language is set to English (even if it's not the language I write in, in that document, but it isn't a problem seemingly).
What I also saw is that, if I remove babel and the references, I can rename my `ToC` and `LoF`, `LoT`. But I need the references though.
Any tip would be very welcome!

Edit: I cannot provide text data from my project, because it is confidential. Here's what I can provide from the main document. Here is what I can include more.

```
\begin{document}
\include{02_front} 
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{blabla} \section{test é è åøæ î}
\appendix
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{80_refs}  
\end{document}
```

Also, I actually finished writing my thesis but I need to summarize it briefly in another language, am would be extremely unwilling to test and remove packages that "might be" not very useful. I literally only have to change these names of `ToC`, `LoF`, `ToF` and references.

Comment: You show a bunch of `packages` but not a line of real code ...

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc And I suggest that you show us a code example that has only the packages necessacry to reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi, I already saw that example, doesn't work :S. I tried to include some more code but I can't include much more than that

Comment: @alexanzi: Your snippets are to be glued together by us, I assume? `\include` statements are useless unless we don't have the relevant file :-(

Comment: @alexanzi -- instead of showing an `\include` statement, you could input dummy text with a `\chapter` and a `\section` that would produce a toc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried to correct some issues, but not all of course.

The commands

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My nice list of contents}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My nice list of figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{My nice list of table}
```

work, regardless whether `babel` is used or not, at best used right before `\begin{document}` or wrapped in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Another option could be using `\settocname` etc. from `tocbibind`, I did not use that here!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.5}
\newenvironment{remark}{\par\mbox{}\par\noindent{\bfseries             \emph{Remark}\/}:\normalfont}{\par}
\newenvironment{defin}{\par\mbox{}\par\noindent\bfseries \emph{\Pointinghand\     }\normalfont}{\par}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
%\pdfcompresslevel=9
\setstretch{1.0} %vertical stretch
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[BoldFont       = AvenirNextRoundedPro-Bold.otf , ItalicFont     =AvenirNextRoundedPro-Italic.otf]{AvenirNextRoundedPro-Reg.otf}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %Adds "References" to toc
\usepackage{titlesec} \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\huge}{\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{1ex}{\vspace{1ex}\filright}[\vspace{0.5ex}\titlerule]
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\makeatletter \patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:}{}{} \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{2em}{6em}} \let\l@table\l@figure  \makeatother % default for 3rd arg: 2.3em - for list of figures and tables
\usepackage{background} 
\definecolor{textcolor}{HTML}{000000}             
\newcommand\Text{c\quad o\quad n\quad f\quad i\quad d\quad e\quad n\quad t\quad i\quad a\quad l} 
\SetBgColor{textcolor}
\SetBgOpacity{0.3}\SetBgAngle{90}
\SetBgPosition{current page.center} 
\SetBgVshift{-0.33\textwidth} 
\SetBgScale{1.8}
\SetBgContents{\sffamily\Text} %for confidential


\usepackage[colorlinks=true, a4paper=true, pdfstartview=FitV,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ hidelinks }

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{My nice list of contents}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My nice list of figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{My nice list of table}

\begin{document}
%\include{02_front} 
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{blabla} \section{test é è åøæ î}
\appendix
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{80_refs}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: actually it worked, thanks ! Installing and changing the  language package to babel worked as well, but well :p Thanks a lot !

Comment: The commands should be placed before calling `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures`for example, not after.

Comment: @s.k: Which commands?

Comment: The 3 first `\renewcommand{}` on top of your post.

Comment: @s.k: You can see, that they  **are** placed before `\tableofcontents`, can't you?

Comment: indeed, but I first tried to copy / paste them at a random place, and this random place was after... So it was just a precision that it won't work if placed after. It should have worked, but it doesn't.

Comment: @s.k: I never said that it would work *after* ;-)

Comment: For me, this didn't work right before `\begin{document}` (i.e., in the preamble), but it did right before `\listoffigures` (i.e., in the document).

Answer (score 2):

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures
```

did the trick for me

Comment: The accepted answer already mentions that.

Comment: If all you want to do is use a different language: `\usepackage[german]{babel}`