# I have one table in my thesis but command \listoftables has words tables in heading {using texstudio}

Tags: table-of-contents

My university suggest list of Table as heading of page

[Can some one please tell me how to change \list of tables command to \list of table]

"Thanks so much for kind and support"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The answers to [Rename ToC, List of Figures, References](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276034/134144) might be interesting. For a more specific advice, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.

Comment: Your query is a bit confusing. Are you asking how to rename the macro `\listoftables` to `\listoftable`, or are you asking how to change the *output* of the `\listoftables` macro so that it outputs "List of Table"? By the way, "List of Table" is a grammatical blunder: In English, the expression "List of <x>", where <x> is a noun, requires the noun <x> to be in *plural* form. This is true even if the list contains just one item. If the header "List of Tables" really bugs you, you should go with "Table", not "List of Table", as the header of the singleton table entry.

Comment: you can reword the title with the links in the first comment (please don't call it list of table though) but if you only have one why list it at all?

Comment: Following from @Mico s comment you could go with "Table List". In any case I think that your university should be informed about its lack of knowledge about English grammar. If you follow its guidelines and they are wrong then it should reflect on them as arbiters not on you as a follower. (I don't have good feelings about many of the typographic requirements that universities place on their authors --- GOM).