# Changing the title of table of contents in LyX

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I've already tried to follow the answer here:
[How to change the title of ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc)

by using `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}`

However, it does not seem to work with `LyX`, neither in the preamble nor as ERT. The package being used is babel.

### Minimum working example of .lyx file:

```
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Innholdsfortegnelse}

1. Innledning

\pagenumbering{arabic} 

Heisann
```

---

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A minimal (non-) working example of code would help to help.

Comment: It should work in a ERT box (obviously before of the table of contents) even with babel.

Comment: That fragment of code is by far not working (it's too minimal). Please provide the `LyX` to `.tex` export of the minimal  code that shows this feature

Comment: [How to change the name of document elements like “Figure”, “Contents”, “Bibliography” etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings...</kbd> > <kbd>Language</kbd> > **Language package:** <kbd>None</kbd>
2. <kbd>Document</kbd> > <kbd>Settings...</kbd> > <kbd>LaTeX Preamble</kbd> >

Write:

```
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\addto\captionsnorsk{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Innholdsfortegnelse}}
```

The result must be the equivalent to this plain LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\addto\captionsnorsk{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Innholdsfortegnelse}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

If doing this you got a `Package babel Error: Unknown language`xxxxx'`:

[image: Mwe]

Then,  go to <kbd>View Complete Log ...</kbd>

[image: mwe]

As you can see, this is because there are an `\select@language {english}` in the `.aux` file of the previous run. You can remove it manually (in the case of the screenshot in a Linux system it was `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.T23297/lyx_tmpbuf6/newfile6.aux`) but you can just click on  <kbd>Close</kbd> and LyX will clean the auxiliary files for you (at least if there are only this error). In next run it should work.

Comment: I got an error message: "Package babel Error: Unknown language `english'. Either you have"

Comment: @PhillipAndreasKarlsen Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{Whatever}}
```

Comment: I tried, it didn't work :(