# Using csname with \addto\captions[language]{}

Tags: macros, babel

The method to change the name of the contents while using the `babel` package
is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/how-to-change-the-title-of-toc).

Per the answer included in the link, the following code may be used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\addto\captionsamerican{% 
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {newContentsName}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

If I wanted to use a variable for the language, I thought I could make the following adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\xLanguage}{american}          % <-- Added this command

\usepackage[\xLanguage]{babel}             % <-- Implemented here

\addto\csname captions\xLanguage\endcsname{% <-- and here
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {newContentsName}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

But this does not work.
Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\csname captions\xLanguage\encsname` must be expanded first, before `\addto` can work with the 'real' command sequence name, i.e. an `\expandafter` is needed before `\addto`.

I.e.  `captions\xLanguage` must be expanded first to yield the content of `\xLanguage`, `american` in the O.P. example, such that `captionsamerican` is usable for `\csname ...\endcsname.

Only after that `\addto\captionsamerican{...}` is finally available.

This is the same code needed for constructing `\newcommand` macros etc. from macronames or parameters etc., i.e.  `\expandafter\newcommand\csname foo\otherfoobar\endcsname{My foo content}`, where `\otherfoobar` contains 'any' token being allowed as a `\newcommand` - defined macro name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\xLanguage}{ngerman}          % <-- Added this command

\usepackage[\xLanguage]{babel}             % <-- Implemented here

\expandafter\addto\csname captions\xLanguage\endcsname{% <-- and here
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Verzeichnisse der tollen Inhalte}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the usefulness of this approach, but you can use `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\xLanguage}{american}          % <-- Added this command

\usepackage[\xLanguage]{babel}             % <-- Implemented here

\csappto{captions\xLanguage}{% <-- and here
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {newContentsName}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatives informative and are always appreciated.