# Changing \contentsname in scrartcl

Tags: table-of-contents, scrartcl

When using the `article` document class, I can customise the title of the table of contents like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

As expected, the title of the table of contents is now "Whatever". However, if I change the first line to use the `scrartcl` document class

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
```

then I'm back to the default "Contents" as the title. I've looked through the KOMA-Script user guide, and it seems like this should still work. I read section 12.4, "Defining Language-Dependent Terms", but a) I didn't understand how to use it, and b) I'm not trying to do anything language-dependent.

**Is there a different/better way to do this in document classes that use KOMA-Script?**

I'm using `xelatex`, if it matters.

Comment: According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539972/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-toc-in-koma-scrbook you should move `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}` below `\begin{document}`.

Comment: It's `scrartcl`, by the way. You should do `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Whatever}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the KOMA commands like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\defcaptionname{\languagename}{\contentsname}{Whatever}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]