# Latex article: unable remove the titles of table of contents, list of figures, list of tables - \contentsname{} doesn't work

Tags: titles, article

I need an article with specific formatting, which I almost got. The problem is that I am not able to delete the default titles of table of contents, list of figures, list of tables and I do not understand why. I post the code:

```
\documentclass[13,titlepage]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=4cm,
            right=1.5cm,
            top=3cm,
            bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
            
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman} % text font
  \setmathfont{XITS Math} % Times Roman math font
\else\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
  % possibly need to choose a suitable math font
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi\fi

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{sectsty} % use 20% "leading"
\sectionfont{\fontsize{13}{1.25}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{13}{1.25}\selectfont}

\usepackage{cite}

\linespread{1.25}
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{13}{14.4}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{13}{10.8}\itshape}




\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{xxxxx1974values,
  title={Values xxxxx},
  author={Xxx, Xxx X.},
  year={1974},
  publisher={Princeton University Press}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{2}

\newpage
\section*{Table of Contents}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\vspace{-1.25cm} % the removed space. Set as appropriate
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\newpage
\section*{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\section*{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\newpage
\section*{List of Abbreviations}


  
\begin{tabular}{ll} 
        
\end{tabular}




\newpage
\section{Section 1}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\pagenumbering{arabic}}
Xx



\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Xx}
Xx

\subsection{Xx}
Xx


\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic - The `article` document class does not recognize -- and simply ignores -- the `13` option.

Answer (score 0):

As one can see in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28518/237192) you have to use

```
\addto\captionsamerican{%
   \renewcommand{\contentsname}{}%
}
```

below loading `babel` instead of renewing `\contentsname`.